# Top/Bottom Padding for Spinner

Tags: android, layout, spinner

How do I specify for a spinner in Android an extra padding on top/bottom of the first/last item? See sample of Goolge below (8 dp spacing).
[image: Google Simple Menu]

Comment: Try these links [1st link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407626/custom-layout-for-spinner-item) [2nd link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946893/android-custom-spinner-layout) [Sample Program](http://mrbool.com/how-to-customize-spinner-in-android/28286) Hope this Help full

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spinner does not support multiple view types.[Issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17128).

I suggested you using dialog for showing your list.

Edited

according to your comment resolved your problem with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16400899/519790)

Comment: The only solution seems to be this one. I found it following your link. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16400899/519790

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a custom adapter for you `Spinner` using your custom layout. Thus, you just need to provide a layout with the proper margin/paddins.

> ```
> Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.myspinner);
> ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.data, R.layout.spinner_item);
> adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
> spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
> ```

You can find a valid example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17213328/2760919).

Answer (score 1):

Just create a separate layout for the items you want to display in the spinner.

Something like this

spinner_text_view.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/customTextView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="15dp"
android:text="@string/sample_list_item"
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Then in your activity/fragment, you can create an adapter (an array adapter to be simple in this case) and pass this layout to that adapter reference. Finally set that adapter to the spinner and you can get the desired result.

Sample code.

```
private void setupSpinner() {
    String[] sampleSpinnerItems = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.spinner_text_view, sampleSpinnerItems);
    sampleSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Note : spinner_text_view is the layout file you have created earlier.

Comment: This doesn't give me extra padding before the first and after the last item.

Answer (score 1):

You need custom adapter for this and custom layouts . 
You can use 2 layouts . Supposing you have n elements to show , in your spinner you ll have n+2. iF the position is 0 (the first element) or the last element you will show the empty layout otherwise you will show the other layout . 
The empty layout you will use for creating this space

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using custom `Adapter` for `Spinner`. It will look like this:

```
class YourAdapter extends BaseArrayAdapter<YourObject> {

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_item, parent, false);
            DropDownViewHolder holder = new DropDownViewHolder();
            holder.root = convertView.findViewById(R.id.drop_down_root);
            // other assignments etc.
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        DropDownViewHolder holder = (DropDownViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        int bottomPadding = 0;
        int topPadding = 0;
        if (position == 0) {
            topPadding = getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin_8);
        } else if (position == (getCount() - 1)) {
            bottomPadding = getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin_8);
        }

        holder.root.setPadding(0, topPadding, 0, bottomPadding);
        // other UI related logic etc.
        return convertView;
    }

    // ...

    public static class DropDownViewHolder {
        View root;
        // other views
    }
}
```

Actually logic with setting extra padding can be changed to changing some stub view visibility to `VISIBLE` or inflating some other layout depending on position, but the solution with padding seems more natural to me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need a custom adapter for this. The following solution works perfectly.

Create a drawable `bg_spinner.xml`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="8dp"
        android:top="8dp" />
    <solid android:color="yourPopupColor" />
</shape>
```

Then set `android:popupBackground="@drawable/bg_spinner_popup"` property for your `Spinner` in XML.

This works like a charm without anything being cut off etc.